# How to pass folder paths in Angular 6 Get API Method?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

In my angular application, I have to pass an Id and a folder path as a parameter in Angular 6.

Please see the below code snippet
in typescript

```
let subDirectory: string = "folder1/folder2/folder3";
let id: number = 6 ;
this.http.get<ItemDetails[]>(this.appService.baseUrl + 'api/File/' + id + "/" + subDirectory)
```

Here the problem is: the API call becomes

this.http.get(this.appService.baseUrl + 'api/File/' + id + "/" + "folder1/folder2/folder3")

if we have only "folder1" as subdirectory then no issues.
"/folder2/folder3" makes the issue

in Controller

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}/{subDirectotry?}")]
 [ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id, string subDirectotry)
 {
 }
```

Please, anyone, help me to achieve the same.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: updated question

Comment: Typescript part is irrelevant here. paste full url you are trying to access and gives you 404

Answer (score 0):

in simple words, define a function to call api in your service

```
getItemsDetails (id: number, subDirectory: string) {
 return this.http.get<ItemDetails[]>(`${this.appService.baseUrl}api/File/${id}/${ subDirectory}`);
}
```

to call in componnet;

```
let subDirectory: string = "folder1/folder2/folder3";
let id: number = 6 ;
this.serviceName.getItemsDetails(id, subDirectory).subscribe(() => {
    // -> do what ever you want do with response.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're getting 404 errors , try to encode the **subDirectory** using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) , then try to ***unescape*** once you receive the request.

Answer (score 0):

You could try catch-all route parameters with `{*}` like below:

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}/{*subDirectotry}")]
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id, string subDirectotry)
{
    return Ok();
}
```